# Number of finite extensions of $p$-adic number field of given degree $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number, $\mathbb{Q}_p$ the $p$-adic number field.
We fix an algebraic closure $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{Q}_p$.
Any algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is assumed to be a subfield of $\Omega$.
Let $n$ be a positive rational integer.

> Is the number of finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of degree $n$ finite?
>   If yes, is there an algorithm to construct all of them?

The motivation is as follows.
Let $p$ be an odd prime number.
I came up with the following result using Hensel's lemma.

> The number of quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is $3$.
>   They are $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt a)$, $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{ap})$, $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt p)$,
>   where $a$ is a quadratic non-residue rational integer mod $p$. $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt a)$ (resp. $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{ap})$) does not depend on the choice of $a$.

Comment: This is Proposition 14, II, §5 of Lang,S.,Algebraic number theory. Unfortunately the proof gives no algorithm for explicit construction.

Comment: See [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2675114/algebraic-closure-of-the-p-adic-integers?noredirect=1#comment5525562_2675114).

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118068/finitely-many-extensions-of-fixed-degree-of-a-local-field?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: For quadratic extensions, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1725761/how-many-quadratic-extension-are-there-on-a-field/1727575#1727575

Answer (score 8):

Maybe the best way to count the *quadratic* extensions of any $p$-adic field $K$ is to use Kummer theory, which says that each such extension is described by a nontrivial element of $K^*/{K^*}^2$. In general, Kummer theory lets you count the cyclic extensions of $K$ degree $n$, as long as the characteristic doesn’t divide $n$, and the $n$-th roots of unity are in $K$. So you can count the cyclic cubic extensions of $\Bbb Q_p$ when $p\equiv1\pmod6$.